# Download resume support blocked by isp?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, download, tcp

Can ISP block resume support for downloads ?

I'm using IDM (internet download manager) to download of the internet from resume supported websites, yet I am unable to resume downloads. I tried different computers with the same result. Turned off firewall, didn't have any effect i was able to download with no issues until a couple of days ago.

Another thing i noticed is that before IDM used to try to connect to several connections to speed up my download, but now it can only connect to one connection.

Also i tried to download using my vpn, and i was able to download and resume downloads with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible for them to do so, yes, either deliberately or accidentally.

Deliberately is fairly unlikely unless the software is doing something pretty strange; I wouldn't expect them to block most attempts.

They could accidentally disrupt that operation, though, by using an HTTP proxy that doesn't do the right thing in the presence of "Range" requests - which are how you ask the remote system to send only part of the data, not the whole thing.

Your best bet, though, is just to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

They do not cheat so visibly
Check and fix your "home router" first http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/

Comment: Tried the link. No Major abberations. TCP and DNS tests were Ok. Disabled router firewall. Also tried another router that i have. Still same thing. If the problem was with my router, would i  be able to download and resume properly using vpn ?

Comment: Since network is completely well:
Please post the url.
And try FDM.